# Connecting docker postgres to pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin-4

Given this `docker-compose.yml`, am experiencing difficulties connecting the docker stack to my pgAdmin.

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: db-user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: db-user
      POSTGRES_DB: db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

For the pgAdmin Connection properties, here's what I've used (others, default values):

- Host: `127.0.0.1`
- Username & Password: `db-user`

And for the error message when saving:

- Error saving properties: UNAUTHORIZED
- Unable to connect to server

Answer (score 0):

The [docker postgresql page](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) suggest the stack.yml:

```
# Use postgres/example user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

And then visit http://localhost:8080.

Or:

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" ...
```

In your case, adding port to the database itself suggests your queries should use that port.

Comment: Is there a way to drop the `adminer` service and leave the `db` service standalone? Well I should just call `docker run`, but if I would add other services, I'll revert back to this file.

Comment: @KaidoShugo sure, you can try it (I don't have access to a docker environment, although https://labs.play-with-docker.com/?stack=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-library/docs/9efeec18b6b2ed232cf0fbd3914b6211e16e242c/postgres/stack.yml is a good start.